# How to format XML using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a table called StoreFolder that contains an XML field called FolderXml.
Each row contains an XML value like the following:

```
<Folder FolderName="test" StoreName="TestStore" />
```

I need to get the Folders in the following XML format:

```
<Folders>
  <Folder FolderName="test1" StoreName="TestStore1" />
  <Folder FolderName="test2" StoreName="TestStore1" />
  <Folder FolderName="test3" StoreName="TestStore1" />
</Folders>
```

I've tried using the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT   FolderXml
FROM     StoreFolder
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Folders')
```

But it outputs the following XML:

```
<Folders>
  <FolderXml>
    <Folder FolderName="test1" StoreName="TestStore1" />
  </FolderXml>
  <FolderXml>
    <Folder FolderName="test2" StoreName="TestStore1" />
  </FolderXml>
  <FolderXml>
    <Folder FolderName="test3" StoreName="TestStore1" />
  </FolderXml>
</Folders>
```

Can someone please show me how to get the XML in the following format (using T-SQL):

```
<Folders>
  <Folder FolderName="test1" StoreName="TestStore1" />
  <Folder FolderName="test2" StoreName="TestStore1" />
  <Folder FolderName="test3" StoreName="TestStore1" />
</Folders>
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are simply missing a convert/cast operation :

```
select Convert(Xml, FolderXml)
  from StoreFolder
for xml path(''), root('Folders')
```

Your `FolderXml` field is being treated as a varchar/nvarchar field, and then added inside an Xml node. Converting it to Xml beforehand ensure that it won't be wrapped in a parent tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
select FolderName as "@foldername",StoreName as "@StoreName"
FROM StoreFolder
FOR XML PATH('Folder'),ROOT('Folder')
```

Comment: It doesn't work as the XML data is stored in a field called FolderXml.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(
    FolderXml XML
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('<Folder FolderName="test1" StoreName="TestStore1" />'),
('<Folder FolderName="test2" StoreName="TestStore1" />'),
('<Folder FolderName="test3" StoreName="TestStore1" />')


SELECT (SELECT T.FolderXml)
FROM @T AS T
FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT('Folders')
```